# Check if an article is about a movie(film)

Tags: wikipedia-api

I need to check if a link pasted by a user is actually a link to a wikipedia article about a movie. I was able to check if the link is a valid Wikipedia article so far, but how do I know it is about a movie and not about something else?

This query returns a non negative page id if the article is a valid Wikipedia page:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Aliens_(film)`

Comment: Maybe [Wikidata](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q104814)?

Comment: @grooveplexit Sorry did not help me. First, how do I get Q104814? Second, how can I conclude from that page that this is indeed a movie?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but you'll need to grab the pageids and then query whether they are an instance of film https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11424

Comment: https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=ask%20%7B%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAliens_(film)%3E%20schema%3Aabout%20%5B%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20%5D%20%7D

Comment: Or `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*` instead of just `wdt:P31`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin why not make it an answer?